# HTML and Twitter URL - regex - Search and Replace

Tags: html, regex, twitter, regexp-replace

this is my full HTML Code to find and replace:

```
    <figure class="wp-block-embed is-type-rich is-provider-twitter wp-block-embed-twitter">
        <div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
            <blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-width="550" data-dnt="true">
                <p lang="en" dir="ltr">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/CrisisCore?src=hash&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">#CrisisCore</a>
                        –Final Fantasy VII– Reunion is coming to PS5, PS4, Xbox Series X|S, Xbox One, Nintendo Switch and Steam on December 13.<br><br>Here&#39;s how it&#39;ll run on each platform.
                    <a href="https:// t.co/ 2IdZP6yQGn">pic.twitter.com/2IdZP6yQGn</a>
                </p>
                &mdash; FINAL FANTASY VII (@finalfantasyvii) 
                <a href="https://twitter.com/finalfantasyvii/status/1593246579489505281?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">November 17, 2022</a>
            </blockquote>
            <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </div>
    </figure>
```

*(Shortner URL to.co dont work in stackoverflow)*

and i need only the Twitter Share URL:
`https://twitter.com/finalfantasyvii/status/1593246579489505281?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw`

and now can i replace this in: `[embed width="550"]$1[/embed]`
but the regex need to serach the full html and replace it in the short code.

Can we say: find the `class= * wp-block-embed-twitter` and find the Twitter-URL (`https://twitter.com/finalfantasyvii/status/1593246579489505281?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw`) and then replace it in the Short-Code?

---

This code changes again and again

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/CrisisCore?src=hash&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">
    #CrisisCore
</a>
–Final Fantasy VII– Reunion is coming to PS5, PS4, Xbox Series X|S, Xbox One, Nintendo Switch and Steam on December 13.<br><br>Here&#39;s how it&#39;ll run on each platform.
<a href="https:// t.co/ 2IdZP6yQGn">pic.twitter.com/2IdZP6yQGn</a>
```

and this code:

```
&mdash; FINAL FANTASY VII (@finalfantasyvii) 
<a href="https://twitter.com/finalfantasyvii/status/1593246579489505281?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">
    November 17, 2022
</a>
```

---

Unfortunately, I have no idea about regex at all. I have familiarized myself with a few examples from https://regex101.com/.
Is there maybe a regex generator?
Or what is the best way to handle so much code with the parser regex?

maybe someone can help me here? Or tell me where I can get help.

Comment: Does that URL contain always `/status/` and `?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw` ?

Comment: if you go on twitter you can see in the "Tweet embed" the Url like this scheme: `https://twitter.com/WalkingDead_AMC/status/1595099944636932097` the ?ref_src could therefore also be deleted

Comment: this is the Twitter URL + "Twitter Username" + status + "Post-ID"

Comment: And wordpress like in the Editor: `[embed width="550"]https://twitter.com/WalkingDead_AMC/status/1595099944636932097[/embed]`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(https:\/\/twitter\.com\/[^\/]+\/status\/\d+)\s*[^"]+
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/H0hdQn/3)

---

`(https:\/\/twitter\.com\/[^\/]+\/status\/\d+)` - match `http://twitter.com/<name>/status/<any number>` as group 1

`\s*[^"]+` - we don't want the parameters, so match until end of parameter `"`

---

The substitution is then:

```
\[embed width="550"\]\g<1>\[/embed\]
```

Comment: the first steps is very nice, THANKS!  But the other code is the "problem". search for the full html, and replace it in the simple code:  `\[embed width="550"\]\g<1>\[/embed\]`
i edit the post up.

Comment: @Sebastian But what is the problem? What language do you use?

Comment: This is an HTML Scraper. Which sees the source code of a web page.